# How to tell if a buffer is a Google Protocol Buffer (Protobuf) message or something else without using exceptions?

Tags: c#, performance, protocol-buffers

TLDR: I need to identify a byte[] as belonging to a protobuf message or not. Is there an efficient way to do this without a try/catch block?

I'm adding in protobuf to an existing set of messages for a C# message monitoring app. I need to parse messages at ~100Hz, and there are about 40 messages in my message set. Currently I attempt to parse a protobuf message using the code:

```
public bool IsProtobuf(byte[] Data){
   try
   {
       Any anyMsg = Any.Parser.ParseFrom(Data);
       bool isProtobuf = anyMsg.Is(protobuf_message.Descriptor);
       if(isProtobuf)
       {
           protobuf_message parsed = protobuf_message.Parser.ParseFrom(Data);
           return true;
       }
   }
   catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException)
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```

However the try/catch blocks REALLY degrade my performance. I go from ~2000Hz message parsing without any protobuf messages to ~25Hz message parsing with all of my protobuf messages.

Is there a faster way to check if a byte[] buffer belongs to a protobuf message or not?

Comment: Exceptions are *not* that slow; are you sure the time isn't coming from parsing large buffers, or the overhead of having right-sized arrays (which means allocations)? But no: protobuf doesn't have any obvious "tells"

Comment: It isn't due to allocations or parsing the buffers, because the messages are still being parsed through other methods. Every incoming message is parsed by every possible message class until a match is found. The GPB messages are only half of my total message count too.

Comment: Exceptions *are* very slow when running an application under a debugger (more so than other things which are slowed down under a debugger) -- make sure you're measuring performance on a standalone release build. If you are, then check if your assumptions are correct with a profiler -- maybe it's not the exception handling that's slow, but the altered behavior from the method returning `false` (and whatever code runs next). Last but not least, though Protobuf may not have a signature, nothing prevents you from adding one yourself so you can check for specific, constant bytes before parsing.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen! What you said about the debugger is correct. It runs significantly better in a release, instead of with a debugger. I was always told try/catch is slow, but now I know when that is true and when it isn't. I need to make sure I check performance in releases instead of in the debugger in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments sum this up, but this is the fastest way you can check without adding identifiers to the protobuf messages yourself. Also the performance hit is only significant if being run with a debugger like I was when I recorded the results in the question. Running in a standalone has much better performance.